# android 4.0 and higher : Copy/paste/cut panel disappears onLongClick Listener on the EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I use PreferenceActivity in the Tabs and add a footer with the editText's :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.assignmentexpert"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
  <TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="2"
    android:stretchColumns="0"
    >
    <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
          style="@style/text_row" 
          android:layout_weight="1"
          >
  <com.customitems.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/taskText"
        style="@style/custom_edittext"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:maxLength="8192"
        android:layout_marginLeft= "25dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        foo:customFont="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        android:hint="@string/hint_assignment_task"/>


  </TableRow>
         <TableRow android:layout_height="1px" android:background="#323232">
    <TextView android:layout_span="1" android:layout_height="1px" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="">
     </TextView>
        </TableRow>
  <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
          style="@style/text_row" 
          android:layout_weight="1"
          >
  <com.customitems.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/taskSpecReq"
        style="@style/custom_edittext"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:maxLength="8192"
        android:layout_marginLeft= "25dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        foo:customFont="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        android:hint="@string/hint_assignment_specific_requirements"/>

     </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

So , when I use LongClick on the `taskTest` EditText, the Copy/paste/cut is appears and works properly. But when I Long click on the `taskSpecReq` my taskSpecReq Copy/paste/cut panel and Tabs disappers from the screen. 
The `taskSpecReq` is in the bottom of the screen.

Long Click on the 1st EditText : 
[image]

Long Click on 2nd EditText:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I used TabHost and nested Activity in it, I solved it by using the

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified"
```

for the TabActivity and for the nested Activity :

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode = "adjustResize"
```

It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the system may be scrolling your view to ensure that the `CustomEditText`'s cursor is visible above the soft keyboard, and so scrolling the top part off the screen.  Check out the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute for your activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

(An easy way to confirm if this is the case is to just switch your two `CustomEditText` widgets.  If the problem always occurs with the bottom one, then this could be it.)

Comment: @RikkiTikkiTavi Wouldn't using `adjustPan` cause the problem?

Comment: I don't know. adjustPan  is working good to get the EditText be focusable properly. Because without it the soft keyboard acts strangly.